# store (get and set) data in Active directory , for example connection string

Tags: c#, active-directory

is there a way to store global data (like connect string etc. ) in active directory and get it in c# function ? 
somthing like

```
AD ad = new ...
ad.Save ("MyConnString",connectionString);
ad.get...
```

Comment: You could make that happen, but then anyone who can query ldap would be able to see it. That is the wrong tool for the job. If this application is in azure you could store the connection string in Azure Key Vault.

Comment: my data aren't sensitive data, i need to publish them in a easy tool, how can i do it.

Comment: Connection strings aren't sensitive? I'm not sure what you mean by "publish", but data is typically stored in a database or a file or even application settings.

Comment: Active Directory isn't suitable for that kind of data - which is very much application-specific, possibly even depending on installation options. Store that in application config files where it belongs

Comment: can you explain the use case of why you want to store the connection string in the Active Directory?

Comment: my app is dependence on  aconnection string wich each user in organization must to setup during install process , i want make it easy , and let AD administrator do it one time for all, the connString is same for all users in same organization, in this case, admin can change also conn string for all (connection string is based on windows authentication )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would update a text attribute on an AD object:

```
var adObj = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{distinguishedName}");
adObj.Properties[attribute].Value = "my connection string";
adObj.CommitChanges();
```

Actually *doing* it is the easy part. Planning it will be the harder part.

Active Directory consists of objects with attributes. So yes, you can store text in any text attribute, but you would have to decide:

1. Which object you will store the data on (`distinguishedName` in the code), and
2. Which attribute you will use (`attribute` in the code)

If the connection string is common for everyone on the domain, you could store it at the root of the domain, but that comes with two problems:

1. Permissions to write to the root of the domain are usually only given to domain admins
2. There are fewer unused attributes that you could choose from.

If you write the connection string to each user object, then it will be easier to find an unused attribute (if you use Exchange, then there are several that start with `extensionAttribute` that are often unused), but you are also duplicating that data on every account and you'll have to hope no one changes it.

Like the commenters above, I would suggest you store this somewhere else. If it is a unique connection string per-domain, then you could just store a mapping table (this domain = this connection string). Once the user logs in, you can see which AD domain they're on and grab the correct connection string.